# xcode11.4 & ionic4 build error: duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework

While trying to build on xcode, the duplicate error above pops up.

I've tried to `pod deintegrate` and `pos install` again, but the error still pops up.

Not sure if error is with the .m and .h files or with the scode build settings.

Any help is appreciated.

This is the error message

```
...



duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_TAGRuntime' in:
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleTagManager/Frameworks/GoogleTagManager.framework/GoogleTagManager(TAGRuntime_b55b9ea65c002f0310978d5f04e96bf2.o)
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/projectName/Plugins/com.jareddickson.cordova.tag-manager/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGRuntime.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_TAGRuntime' in:
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleTagManager/Frameworks/GoogleTagManager.framework/GoogleTagManager(TAGRuntime_b55b9ea65c002f0310978d5f04e96bf2.o)
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/projectName/Plugins/com.jareddickson.cordova.tag-manager/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGRuntime.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_CLASS_$_TAGUniversalAnalytics' in:
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleTagManager/Frameworks/GoogleTagManager.framework/GoogleTagManager(TAGUniversalAnalytics_398262d418b53042dc4e5b4d94f50e24.o)
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/projectName/Plugins/com.jareddickson.cordova.tag-manager/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGUniversalAnalytics.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_TAGUniversalAnalytics._defaultItemMap' in:
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleTagManager/Frameworks/GoogleTagManager.framework/GoogleTagManager(TAGUniversalAnalytics_398262d418b53042dc4e5b4d94f50e24.o)
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/projectName/Plugins/com.jareddickson.cordova.tag-manager/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGUniversalAnalytics.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_TAGUniversalAnalytics._defaultTransactionMap' in:
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleTagManager/Frameworks/GoogleTagManager.framework/GoogleTagManager(TAGUniversalAnalytics_398262d418b53042dc4e5b4d94f50e24.o)
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/projectName/Plugins/com.jareddickson.cordova.tag-manager/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGUniversalAnalytics.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_TAGUniversalAnalytics._numberFormatter' in:
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleTagManager/Frameworks/GoogleTagManager.framework/GoogleTagManager(TAGUniversalAnalytics_398262d418b53042dc4e5b4d94f50e24.o)
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/projectName/Plugins/com.jareddickson.cordova.tag-manager/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGUniversalAnalytics.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_TAGUniversalAnalytics._productDimensionRegex' in:
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleTagManager/Frameworks/GoogleTagManager.framework/GoogleTagManager(TAGUniversalAnalytics_398262d418b53042dc4e5b4d94f50e24.o)
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/projectName/Plugins/com.jareddickson.cordova.tag-manager/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGUniversalAnalytics.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_TAGUniversalAnalytics._productMetricRegex' in:
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleTagManager/Frameworks/GoogleTagManager.framework/GoogleTagManager(TAGUniversalAnalytics_398262d418b53042dc4e5b4d94f50e24.o)
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/projectName/Plugins/com.jareddickson.cordova.tag-manager/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGUniversalAnalytics.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_IVAR_$_TAGUniversalAnalytics._turnOffAnonymizeIpValues' in:
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleTagManager/Frameworks/GoogleTagManager.framework/GoogleTagManager(TAGUniversalAnalytics_398262d418b53042dc4e5b4d94f50e24.o)
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/projectName/Plugins/com.jareddickson.cordova.tag-manager/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGUniversalAnalytics.o)
duplicate symbol '_OBJC_METACLASS_$_TAGUniversalAnalytics' in:
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/Pods/GoogleTagManager/Frameworks/GoogleTagManager.framework/GoogleTagManager(TAGUniversalAnalytics_398262d418b53042dc4e5b4d94f50e24.o)
    /Users/wai/Documents/projectfile/platforms/ios/projectName/Plugins/com.jareddickson.cordova.tag-manager/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a(TAGUniversalAnalytics.o)
ld: 334 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)A
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after I updated my pods and Xcode at the same time. What fixed it for me was:

I commented out every pod in the podfile as well as the `use_frameworks!` line. I then ran `pod install` again, which uninstalled all pods. I uncommented everything in my podfile again. Ran again `pod install` to reinstall the pods. In Xcode I cleaned the build folder. ( Product > Clean Build Folder ) and everything was working.